# Site is not opening with IE

Tags: web-application, iis, internet-explorer, web, chrome

I have a **Claims-Based web application** with a site collection.

I can not **open the site from IE** (neither from SharePoint Designer, it prompts for credentials) but it **works fine from Chrome**.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the **Claims Authentication Type**, it was setted to *Kerberos*.
I changed it (for the *default zone*) to **NTLM** and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it may be something simple, try entering fully qualified credentials for example domain\username

Comment: no, I checked that. I guess is some IIS settings

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if its not the LoopBackCheck issue?

Please check [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_foxhole/archive/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way.aspx) link, it may help you to fix that.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks, but It is working fine with other web applications, so I do not think so

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Probably you have saved credentials in your browser. Can you please try this?

1. Start -> Run -> cmd -> rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr
2. Remove “yoursite.com” from the list
3. Avoid using “save credentials” in the browser going forward.